# GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

## Problem

When I try to use `GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer` I get a "`WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:`" followed by two errors inside a "MultiException":

- "`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL`"
- "`Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor`"

## I've Tried

I am not knowledgeable in Jersey, but I have:

- Read [this similar, unsolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40786059/3399416) from seven months ago, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29037111/3399416) from two years ago.
- Learned that the ResourceConfig [is meant to replace/simplify a web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42228026/3399416), but this project has no existing (and thus, no conflicting) web.xmls.
- Removed the underscores and changed the port number in the URI (`http://127.0.0.1:8086/the_uri/`). Didn't work.

## In-depth

#### ResourceConfig I'm using:

```
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyResourceConfig(){
        register(CORSResponseFilter.class);

        register(MyAPIPoint.class);
    }
}
```

Contains two classes being registered and nothing else.

#### Truncated Error Stack Trace:

```
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor.<init>(WadlModelProcessor.java:96)
    ...
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:116)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:395)
    ...
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:116)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

([It's  OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601098/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-wadl-json-in-creating-jersey-rest-client) and [this issue thread](https://github.com/ContainX/openstack4j/issues/123) it seems that I might have a conflict in my dependencies.

Relevant dependencies: I'm using **jersey 2.11** and **tyrus-container-grizzly-server 1.13**.

**Edit:** 
Updated the jersey version to **2.25** in the pom and the error disappeared.

If someone wants to try and give a better solution or explanation I can give more information about the setup of the project. I won't accept this answer as it is not complete.